# Choropleth Google Geochart: colorAxis Not Styling Map

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, choropleth

So I've done a lot of searching but no one else seems to be having this problem. I've found 3 formats for changing the colorAxis as part of the options for a visualization, but neither work.

```
var map_options = {};
map_options['colorAxis'] = {colors ['red', 'blue']};
```

Attempt #2

```
var map_options = {
colorAxis: {colors ['red', 'blue']},
};
```

Attempt #3

```
var map_options = {
colorAxis: {
colors: ['red', 'blue']
}
};
```

The Rest of the Code

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['geomap']});

    function drawVisualization() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['State', 'Homicide Rate (per 100,000 in 2012)'],
  ['Alabama', 7.1],
  ['Alaska', 4.1],
  ['Arizona', 5.5],
  ['Arkansas', 5.9],
  ['California', 5],
  ['Colorado', 3.1],
  ['Connecticut', 4.1],
  ['Delaware', 6.2],
  ['Florida', 5.2],
  ['Georgia', 5.9],
  ['Hawaii', 2.1],
  ['Idaho', 1.8],
  ['Illinois', 5.8],
  ['Indiana', 4.7],
  ['Iowa', 1.5],
  ['Kansas', 2.9],
  ['Kentucky', 4.5],
  ['Louisiana', 10.8],
  ['Maine', 1.9],
  ['Maryland', 6.3],
  ['Massachusetts', 1.8],
  ['Michigan', 7],
  ['Minnesota', 1.8],
  ['Mississippi', 7.4],
  ['Missouri', 6.5],
  ['Montana', 2.7],
  ['Nebraska', 2.9],
  ['Nevada', 4.5],
  ['New Hampshire', 1.1],
  ['New Jersey', 4.4],
  ['New Mexico', 5.6],
  ['New York', 3.5],
  ['North Carolina', 4.9],
  ['North Dakota', 4],
  ['Ohio', 4.3],
  ['Oklahoma', 5.7],
  ['Oregon', 2.4],
  ['Pennsylvania', 5.4],
  ['Rhode Island', 3.2],
  ['South Carolina', 6.9],
  ['South Dakota', 3],
  ['Tennessee', 6],
  ['Texas', 4.4],
  ['Utah', 1.8],
  ['Vermont', 1.3],
  ['Virginia', 3.8],
  ['Washington', 3],
  ['West Virginia', 3.9],
  ['Wisconsin', 3],
  ['Wyoming', 2.4]
      ],
   false);

      var map_options = {};

      map_options['region']= 'US';
      map_options['width']= '900px';
      map_options['height']= '500px';
  
    
      var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(
       
          document.getElementById('visualization'));
      geomap.draw(data, map_options);
    };

   
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

```html
<body>
<div id="map-title">Homicide Rates (per 100,000) in the United States: 2012</div><br>
<div id="visualization" style="width: 900; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try `var map_options = {colors:['red','blue']}`